# Leaflet routing machine get route summary without drawind route

Tags: leaflet, javascript

I am using LRM to calculate routes. And I need data about this routes. Now I'm just learning how to exctract this data so I can use it further. 
I have two routes

```
var routing1 =  L.Routing.control({
            waypoints: [
                L.latLng(54.736038, 55.97429),
                L.latLng(54.736985, 55.980878),
            ],
        });

var routing2 =  L.Routing.control({
            waypoints: [
                L.latLng(54.732798, 55.969934),
                L.latLng(54.734954, 55.95809)
            ],
        });
```

I have a button to draw this routes

```
document.getElementById("drawing").addEventListener("click", myFunction);
        function myFunction() {
            routing1.addTo(map).on('routesfound', function (e) {
                distance = e.routes[0].summary.totalDistance;
                console.log('routing1 ' + distance);
            });
            routing2.addTo(map).on('routesfound', function (e) {
                distance = e.routes[0].summary.totalDistance;
                console.log('routing2 ' + distance);
            });
        }
```

As I don't quite understand JS yet so I have this question:

---

How can I console.log route's summary the moment route calculated? Without drawing it.

Comment: Just leave out `addTo(map)` call: `routing1.on( ...`.

Comment: @TomazicM tried it cause it looks legit but nothing happens in that case. Only with addTo and I don't get why it works that way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT1**: Solution below was first attempt. It is working, but is quite complicates. See simple solution at EDIT2.

Upon investigation it turns out that quite a big part of routing process depends on adding `L.Routing.control` to map. To force route calculation and prevent showing of route on the map requires some hacking trickery:

1. Itinerary display must be prevented with `show: false` option.
2. Endpoints marker display must be prevented by dummy marker creation option `createMarker: function(p1,p2) {}`.
3. Internal `_updateLines` method has to be replaced with dummy method.
4. Routing control must be added to map with `onAdd(map)` method.

Final code then looks something like this:

```
var wayPoint1 = L.latLng(57.74, 11.94);
var wayPoint2 = L.latLng(57.6792, 11.949);

var bounds = L.latLngBounds(wayPoint1, wayPoint2); 

var myRouting = L.Routing.control({
    waypoints: [wayPoint1, wayPoint2],
    routeWhileDragging: true,
    show: false,
    createMarker: function(p1,p2) {}
});

myRouting.on('routesfound', function (e) {
    distance = e.routes[0].summary.totalDistance;
    console.log('routing distance: ' + distance);
});

// save original mathed for later use
var _updateLines = myRouting._updateLines;

myRouting._updateLines = function (p1) { };

map.fitBounds(bounds);
myRouting.onAdd(map);
```

**EDIT2**: Much simpler solution uses `L.Routing.osrmv1` routing method:

```
var map = L.map('map');

L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '© OpenStreetMap contributors'
}).addTo(map);

var wayPoint1 = L.latLng(57.74, 11.94);
var wayPoint2 = L.latLng(57.6792, 11.949);

rWP1 = new L.Routing.Waypoint;
rWP1.latLng = wayPoint1;    

rWP2 = new L.Routing.Waypoint;
rWP2.latLng = wayPoint2;    

var myRoute = L.Routing.osrmv1();
myRoute.route([rWP1, rWP2], function(err, routes) {
    distance = routes[0].summary.totalDistance;
    console.log('routing distance: ' + distance);
});

map.fitBounds(L.latLngBounds(wayPoint1, wayPoint2));
```

Comment: See much simpler solution at EDIT2 section.